# I want to convert the data type string to an Array in javascript like "['123','234]" to ['123','234']

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method that gets an array in the form of a string like `"['123', '245345','2345']"` I want to convert it to an array datatype. Here I want to remove the quotes and want the type to be an array. How can I do it easily in JS?

```
Input: "['123','234']" // string
output: ['123','234']  //array datatype
```

Comment: Are you sure that you get it like that (with single quotes around the numbers)? And not as regular JSON (that should have double quotes to enclose strings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```js
// Turn it into valid JSON (strings are doublequotes)
const inputUnformatted = "['123', '245345','2345']";
const inputFormatted = inputUnformatted.replaceAll("'", `"`); 
const result = JSON.parse(inputFormatted);
console.log(result); // (3) [123, 245345, 2345]
```

Comment: Because somehow I got it into my mind that they wanted an array of numbers :v

Comment: Need the array of strings and the datatype should be changed from string to array.

Comment: Which is what it does?

Comment: I mean after what you did. If you check typeof result it will remain string and not array

Comment: @andridomace that's an array

Comment: @andridomace I don't believe that you did. Here's a codepen of it https://codepen.io/inabahare/pen/qBLjZjg?editors=1111

Answer (score -2):

You can try as follows

```
const myString = "['123', '234']";


const outputString = myString.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "[$1]");

console.log(outputString);
```

**Output:**

['123', '234']

Comment: output here is a string, not an array

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: it does not, OP wants it as an array, not a string

Comment: @GafiCode Look what he needed in output.

Comment: datatype remains as string

Comment: @LeanLearner yes, they need an array

Answer (score -3):

If you change the format of the input a bit you will be able to use `JSON.parse`.
It will accept only JSON valid inputs, which in this case should be `'["123", "234"]'` and not `"['123','234']"`.

```js
JSON.parse('["123", "234"]') // => ['123', '234']
```

Comment: that is not OP's string

Comment: also, I don't understand how could you post this answer AFTER the question was closed:  `Closed 1 hour ago by Ivar, VLAZ` but this was `answered 39 mins ago`